# Angular UI with Bound Data Won't Show Until a Click happens

Tags: angular

The UI of this Angular app will no longer display any bound data (menu, component info, etc) until a click is made on something that has a function. Quick video here that's big enough to see:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kn8L700whfCpDMnzX5iYDyrOgw424BbR/view

[image]

This is a working site with continuous integration and I just can't imagine what I've done that is now causing this to happen. I recently upgraded to Angular 10, and it was working fine after that, so I don't believe that's the issue. I've never seen this before and not even sure what to search on because I have been very unsuccessful so far. Any advice/ideas is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I've just went to production server and took last update from 7/15 and placed in staging area and it loads as expected. Went to DevOps to do a comparison between that commit and yesterday's commit (when this began) and I don't see anything in Angular project except for a couple new components, which are not part of any initial loading. Only other changes were in an API project and a docker file at base of solution. What else can I look into?

Comment: You have some error/warning on open or refresh page?

Comment: check what is rendered before you click. somewhere render stops and that place could be the issue

Comment: @TomaszVizaint there are no errors or warnings. The debug console looks normal with my comments showing data is being pulled as expected.

Comment: @Andrei what is shown as rendered is static HTML. What's not being rendered until the click is everything that is bound. Do you think attempting to go through every lifecycle event can provide some insight? What do you suggest to be looking for?

Comment: do you mean all the html is in place, but it is invisible for some reason ?

Comment: @Andrei on the default template, all the hard coded html is showing...anything that is a component is not showing until that first click happens. Once the click happens, it all displays.The console shows all the data has already been grabbed...components just not showing until a click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not saying this is the answer, but after insurmountable amount of research and attempts to figure out what was going on, the only thing I was able to do to make it work was to add a change detector to my global template:

app

- default-layout.component - *which holds the*  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
  ...
  this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

It's not an answer I'm satisfied with because it doesn't tell me the reason why, or what was happening, but it is a solution that worked here. Thanks for the help and hope that may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was an error on the page. After fixing an error like below, the page start rendering the content of router outlet properly.

> main.ts:5  ERROR Error: NG01050: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.

You'll want to add a `formGroup` directive and pass it an existing `FormGroup` instance (you can create one in your class).